# Code in application.js not loading in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, web-services

I just launched [my web service](http://foriio.com/) 
and just found out that my application.js is not working...

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .

$("body").on('click', 'ul#invite_links li#invite_link_facebook a', function () {
  var url = $(location).attr('href');
    FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    link: url
  });
});

$("body").on('click', '#facebook_friends button', function () {
  var receiver_name = $(this).find(".facebook-friend-name").text();
  var receiver_img = $(this).find(".facebook-friend-avatar   img").attr("src");
  $("#facebook_avatar").val(receiver_img);
  $("#collaborator_user_account").val(receiver_name);
  $("#collaborator_user_account").attr("readonly", "readonly");
  $("#collaborator_job_name").focus();
});

$("body").on('click', '#modal-close', function () {
  $(".modal").hide();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.notice').stop().animate({'marginTop':'-30'},850).delay(3000).slideUp(500);
});
```

This should be working when user access
work page and try to add collaborator through searching friends in facebook.
[example here](http://www.foriio.com/works/18)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is so because you are not requiring the current file itself. Following is how would you do so:

```
//= require_self
```

Please note that `//= require_tree .` does load the current tree/directory, but it doesn't load the code in the file: application.js itself.

Edit: If still your code doesn't work, you have to have your JS code inside `$(document).ready` callback so that it gets executed when all the other asset files load properly.

Comment: It depends. If you want to load the current file before the rest of tree, write `//= require_self` before `//= require_tree .` and vice versa.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I added but still not working... even the #modal-close doesn't respond...

Comment: Please write all the js stuff inside `$(document).ready()` so that it loads when the HTML and CSS had loaded properly.

Comment: oh, im so sorry. I acutally misunderstood you. I added $(function(){ $(document).ready(function(){  in every single one of js code I wrote and it didn't work. So I thought this was something different from yours. Thanks for the support Bilal Maqsood!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and in my case all I had to do was run
`yarn build --watch`